# Excel VBA Type Mismatch with If function

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and have been teaching myself for the last week. I have taken on a task that is maybe a bit to complex for me.

I have a document with columns A - AE
I need to go through this document and move information on to separate sheets, depending on what it is.
I am now trying to use an IF statement that needs to match 2 requirements before it moves the information. I can get each individual requirement to work but not both together as keep getting a Type Mismatch error.

I have no idea what i am doing wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub copyrows()

    Dim Test As Range, Cell As Object

    Set Test = Range("G2:Z4000") 'Substitute with the range which includes your True/False values

    For Each Cell In Test

        If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Cell.Value = "Refund" And "Commission" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheet3.Select 'Substitute with your sheet
            ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is `Cell` an `Object`? I'd make it a `Range` instead, because that's what you're using it as.  While `Object` *may* work, `Range` is better I believe.

Answer (score 3):

`If Cell.Value = "Refund" And "Commission" Then`

Should instead read:

`If Cell.Value = "Refund" Or Cell.Value = "Commission" Then`

You have to be explicit with each condition separated by boolean operators like AND or OR.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is already mentioned in the answer above by @IanL

However, your code is far from being optimized.

You can replace your 5 lines:

```
 Cell.EntireRow.Copy
 Sheet3.Select 'Substitute with your sheet
 ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
 Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

With 1:

```
Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Which is not using `Select`, `ActiveSheet`, or `Selection`, just using fully qualified `Range` object.